# what is virbr0 and can I uninstall libvirt-daemon and not have a problem?

Tags: libvirt

A clean install of RHEL/CentOS 7.9 from dvd results in the network interface of `virbr0` being present.

I don't like that and want to get rid of it by doing `yum remove libvirt-daemon`.

In doing that, do I set myself up for future problems?  Can I get a quick explanation of what `virbr0` would ever be used for and if I should keep it why?

Comment: virbr0 is virtual bridge that virtual machines use to connect to external network, set up by libvirt. You should be able to remove libvirt safely if you don't plan to run VMs on your system, but you can also just disable it

Comment: also notice that it's really not using any resources lest you actually use it. It's still wise to remove it if not needed, if only for the inherent beauty of not running unused services.